# winform mdi catch child form focus c#

Tags: winforms, forms, focus, mdi

I would like to be able to catch a child window focus event, in an mdi form.

If i loose focus to the entire mdi application, then click on a child, it works, but if I had two child forms open, I cannot catch the focus event when clicking between them.

I am using Dotnet Framework 2.0, and I need the code solution that will run fine on a windows 2000 machine, and up.

Thanks in advance for all help and advice,

-regards 
Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`Form.MdiChildActivate` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildactivate.aspx). This event will be fired in your MDI parent form.

Answer (score 1):

override the child forms Activated event.

sample code:

```
private void addChild(){
        frmChild mychild = new frmChild();
        mychild.Activated += FActivated;
        mychild.MdiParent = this;
        mychild.Show();
}

private void FActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Activated one of the child.");
}
```